# Jquery function not identified in Asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, global-asax

I have Client side function in `Jquery` name `myFunction`

```
function myFunction (){

alert('Hello');
}
```

on Server side I call this function using this code

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "tmp", "<script type='text/javascript'>$(function(){myFunction();});</script>", false);
```

it works fine when my Url is `Home.aspx` , and when I make a file of type `Global.asax` and make new Url from my home for example `Home` it also workes fine , but when I make another new Url for example `Home/Category/1` this gives me a Javascript error saying that `myFuntion` is not defined

I searched and googled but couldnt get anything helpful.

Comment: Well is it defined on the page?

Comment: What do you mean ? which type of things ?

Comment: @rabarkareem: The order in which things are defined in JavaScript is important.  You can't call a function until it's been defined.  So when you're getting that error, it would seem that either the function isn't being defined at all or is being defined *after* the attempt to call it.  Can you examine the client-side code to determine which of these cases is true?  And where in your page structure(s) do you put this client-side code?  (Both the function definition and the call to it.)

Comment: I know that the order is important in `Javascript` the server code that I've mentioned above is in my `Page_Load` of Home.aspx page , and it adds the script at the end of my page , bellow the defined function , and as I mentioned it works fine with `localhost/Home` url , but when I change my url to `localhost/Home/Category/1` it cant recognize the function , I think the problem is with Global.asax while it changes the url